# How can I record audio and play other tracks as backtrack at the same time?

Tags: recording, keyboard, daw, ableton-live

I'm using a Nord Stage and a Windows 10 laptop, and I want to record an audio (not MIDI) track on top of existing tracks. So I'd like to hear the keyboard and the backtrack, and record just the keyboard.

I tried to just connect the keyboard to the line in. But then I get a terrible latency. Then I found ASIO4ALL drivers, and using that in combination with Ableton Live, the latency problem is solved. But ASIO4ALL uses the output exclusively so then I can hear either just my keyboard input or just the backtracks, not both at the same time.

I've also got a simple Behringer XENYX 502. Perhaps I could use the tape in and out ports to mix keyboard in and e.g. phone in on which I play some backtrack. But that's very inconvenient because each time I want to update the backtrack with a newly recorded track I've got to transfer it to my phone first.

Is an external audio interface going to help me out here? There's a huge price range and a lot to choose from, what would be a simple, cheap solution to my challenge?

Comment: When you have the track you are recording to record armed in Ableton live, you can't hear your keyboard?

Comment: @ToddWilcox I can, but I cannot hear the backtrack at the same time when using ASIO4ALL drivers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want to hear the audio of the backtrack, be sure to put it in the same output. as your question explains, you play the backtrack outside the DAW. This happens due to an exclusive override of ASIO4ALL to the soundcard driver.

two possible cheap solution:

-to import your backtrack into the DAW.

-to buy usb soundcard and make it as the windows output. the cheap one is: http://www.ebay.com/itm/Nw-Blue-External-USB-2-0-to-3D-Virtual-Audio-Sound-Card-Adapter-Converter-7-1-CH-/300715727779

It is a lot better to use an audio interface for recording audio.and onboard soundcard is highly not recommended for professional recording.
focusrite, m-audio and presonus soundcards are available at a low price. you should check it out.

Comment: I ended up using my m-audio midi keyboard and investing some time learning vst's. Much lighter setup and works great. Thanks anyway.

Comment: you're welcome. and good luck for you.